# PDFBox on Android

Tags: android, pdfbox

I'm trying to read PDF and show the content on Android using PDFbox. I can only read PDF and show it in Android webview. Can anybody tell me how to show the PDF in another way?  Or maybe PDFBox is not compatible with Android?

Answer (score 3):

PDFBox (lastest release, 1.5) is not compatible with Android.

-- update --

Correct, like @Gili said, because of AWT dependencies. Android has no AWT nor Swing related classes in its Runtime.

Comment: PDFBox requires AWT which is not available on Android.

Comment: The answer applies also to 1.8 and 2.0 versions.

Answer (score 1):

I recently did a port of PDFBox to Android. This is only for text extraction from PDF documents.
You can find it here - https://github.com/RatheeshRavindran/PDFBoxLight
Please note it is still a 'Beta' release.

Comment: I just tried your PDFBoxLight package/solution, BUT the PdfManager.ToText() function doesn't retrieve any data from the pdf file(?)....

Comment: the "PDFTextStripper.getText()" function, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

PDFs cannot be created using PDFbox in Android