# How to show pdf file and edit content in android

Tags: android, pdf-viewer

I want to open PDF file from locally and then I show the PDF content then if user copy any text then I want to get the copied text. so please suggest me any API or solution related to this problem and the challenging task is to copy text and get it that I want. I have use this code also but its open PDF by using internal app like adobe reader so I don't know that adobe reader give me permission to access copy text.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.pdf");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Please regard that if you try to open a protected PDF-File the user won't be able to copy any text of it.

Comment: actually pdf file is not protected and my point is this i want to show pdf and when user copy the text then i m able to get that selected text and i dont know how to do this..

Answer (score 6):

[PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) would be your best option considering how easy it is to use.
You can have a look at the [examples](http://pdfbox.apache.org/userguide/text_extraction.html) and get going immediately..

**EDIT :** As @Adinia pointed it out, PDFBox is not working on Android. The reason being PDFBox uses AWT and Swing even for the non-ui related tasks and Android does not support these.

You could have a go at [PDFjet](http://pdfjet.com/os/edition.html) and here are some [examples](http://pdfjet.com/java/by-example.html) to get you started.

**EDIT 2:** **[PDFBox-Android](https://github.com/Birdbrain2/PdfBox-Android)** (as the name suggests) is now available for Android, as @Theo was so kind to inform.

Comment: hey swayam by using pdfbox api able to show pdf and if i copy any text then it give that text and please give me one example how to use it...

Comment: PDFBox is not working with Android, see related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6221455/469983  , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980668/how-to-add-pdfbox-to-an-android-project/8997074#8997074

Comment: If pdfbox not used with android so what i use now.

Comment: @AshutoshBansal : I will try to come up with something and let you know. Sorry.

Comment: Maybe try PDFjet. I have given the link in my updated answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Try PDFjet. It should work. Not sure though. Havnt used it myself.

Comment: There's now a PDFBox port for Android: https://github.com/Birdbrain2/PdfBox-Android