# how to use birdbrain2 - pdfbox for android

Tags: android, eclipse, pdfbox

[there is](https://github.com/Birdbrain2/PdfBox-Android) a link to get a pdfbox library that should works with Android!
(i refer to [that SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536332/android-jre-system-libary-java-awt-is-missed/32048562#32048562), please have a look before)

BUT how should I use it?

-> just extract the ZIP files/repertories into /libs?

-> how make it part of my Android project?

Thanks.

***EDIT:***

I already tried severals light (like this: stackoverflow.com/questions/5813217/pdfbox-on-android?rq=1) pdfbox releases (since the normal release seems not to work under android) , but no one works for me!

And I don't know what to do to get through anymore! :( I really need to parse a PDF file in my android app, but just can't deal with it.

In addition, the V1 of my android app is 100% working, without the PDF part (my V2).

Comment: You could improve your question by telling what IDE you are using, add it in the labels, and also mention what you tried already. See also at https://github.com/Birdbrain2/PdfBox-Android/releases , there are normal .jar files.

Comment: Eclipse. I already tried severals light (like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813217/pdfbox-on-android?rq=1) pdfbox releases (since the normal release seems not to work under android) , but no one works for me! And I don't know what to do to get through anymore! :( I really need to parse a PDF file in my android app, but just can't deal with it.

Comment: What I meant is that you edit the question and add the label. I can't help you, but an improved question may result in others seeing the question and being able to help. Your question is basically a android IDE newbie question, i.e. how to add the jars. Do also mention if you have been able to build ANY android project.

Comment: NO because this ZIP file, DOESN'T contain any JAR file............ if it was the case I won't be here asking for help! ;-)

Comment: I suspect you downloaded a source pack. That's why I pointed you to the link in my first comment. That one has the jar.

Comment: Ok, download in progress! ;-) Will let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To whom it may concern, if it can help someone else:

Ok, the JAR given by Tilman works for me (pdfbox-android-1.8.7.jar)!
Thanks  a lot for your help! ;-)

Now I still have an OutOfMemoryError (Out of memory on a 65034-byte allocation), but that's an android problem I have to fix too. But that's another story.